# DDR_XCK register in atmega328

Tags: atmega, datasheet, register

Page 166 of [datasheet of atmega328](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) shows the use of a register called `DDR_XCK`.

```
When using synchronous mode (UMSELn = 1), the Data Direction Register
for the XCKn pin (DDR_XCKn) controls whether the clock source is internal (Master mode) or
external (Slave mode). The XCKn pin is only active when using synchronous mode.
```

No sign of it in the `io.h` file associated with the atmega328, nor in the register summary section. Where I can find infos about it ?

Comment: PD4 in atmega328 is XCK pin. So the Data Direction Register for the XCKn (PD4) pin is DDRD register.

Answer (score 1):

Section 13.2, There you have the data direction registers for every port, just choose the register and bit that matches your clock pin (XCKn)

it's definitely not written in the most clear way